# Le mot anglais « race »

Tags: traduction, anglais

Il a été répété assez souvent qu'en français le mot « race » n'est applicable qu'aux animaux et ne signifie rien en ce qui concerne les êtres humains. C'est le mot qui traduisait l'anglais « race ». La question qui se pose est évidente. Prenons par exemple une phrase d'anglais au hasard comme la suivante.

> The paper asserted that "Europeanization" (*la europeizacion*) was the "supreme ideal of the Latin American world" and that "we are not the enemies of the yellow race, whose abilities the prosperous and strong Japan has plainly shown: we only want to note that because of the form of its civilization, it is not suitable to meld with the nationalities of the Americas… Not even the ashes of the men of the Asian race should perpetually rest far from their homeland. […] The bulk of our population is comprised of the white race of Hispanic origin and that white race is the essential core, […] (Race and Transnationalism in the Americas - Benjamin Bryce, ‎David M. K. Sheinin · 2021)

Qu'advient-il en français de ces termes comme « yellow race » et « Asian race » ? Peut-on savoir ce qui a été prévu pour de telles traductions ?

Rien de cette nouvelle pratique d'élimination du mot « race » de la langue française ne semble avoir transpiré dans les rouages de DeepL et Google Translate. Les traductions sont « race jaune » et « race asiatique » (mis à part que Google Translate penche pour « course jaune ».

Doit-on réduire des phrases entières à néant dans les traductions, ou simplement ignorer les directives plus ou moins officielles qui émanent des autorités en la matière ?

*Autres  examples*

> Using data from the National Health Measurement Study (NHMS) we examined the relationship between health and race (African Americans and Whites) using five different HRQoL measures. (*The relationship of five health related quality of life ...Shani Anika Herrington · 2006)

> Leading with Race: The Center for Third World Organizing and ...
> Larry Raphael Salomon · 2005

> Representing the Race: Indentity and Race-consciousness in ...
> Keith D. Leonard · 1999

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145851/discussion-on-question-by-lph-le-mot-anglais--race-).**

Comment: @Luke Sawczak : closing the question because of a debatable reason and (re)moving all comments is a puzzling form of censorship.

Comment: @Graffito Cleaning up comment threads is well-supported by SE policy. We have so many 20+ comment thread notifications here and the recommended action (as described by the wordy template I tend to truncate) is to relocate the discussion to chat.

Comment: As for closing, that is also not deletion, which is another option available to moderators and one I didn't think fit here. (It is perhaps unfortunate that moderators lose the ability to vote to close: we can only unilaterally and instantly close.) The community has a prerogative to close questions it thinks will not lead to a fruitful exchange of knowledge. Feel free to vote to reopen it and/or discuss my reasoning in [the meta question Anne Aunyme posed](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/928/comment-traiter-les-questions-politiquement-charg%c3%a9es).

Answer (score 4):

> ## Définition :
>
> Regroupement arbitraire d'êtres humains qui se distingueraient par des traits physiques communs héréditaires, généralement la couleur de leur peau, sans égard à leur culture ou à leur pays d'origine.
>
> ## Note :
>
> Utilisé dès le XVIe siècle, le terme race désigne alors l'ensemble des membres (ascendants et descendants) d'une même famille, ou d'un même peuple. Au cours du XVIIIe siècle, on tente un « découpage » de l'espèce humaine en races distinctes. Cette idéologie servira d'assise au racisme et à ses pratiques, qui atteindra son apogée lors de la Deuxième Guerre mondiale. Une prise de conscience sur cette notion de « race » forcera la communauté scientifique à s'y pencher, en s'appuyant notamment sur les avancées de la génétique. **La conclusion des travaux menés fera l'unanimité : le concept de races humaines distinctes est non fondé scientifiquement.** Il a donc progressivement été abandonné au profit de l'idée d'un être humain universel.
> [...]
> Le terme *race*, en raison de son évolution et de son caractère scientifiquement non applicable chez l'espèce humaine, est perçu par certains comme étant porteur d'une charge péjorative. Son utilisation, en parlant des êtres humains, tend à disparaître des discours officiels. On préférera dire, par exemple, *un homme noir, une femme blanche, un Asiatique*. D'un point de vue strictement linguistique, ce terme entre dans la formation de dérivés (*racisme, raciste, interracial*, etc.) qui correspondent à des concepts souvent incontournables.
>
> [ Office québécois de la langue française, « [race](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/8355169/race) », je souligne ]

---

> Doit-on réduire des phrases entières à néant dans les traductions, ou
> simplement ignorer les directives qui émanent du gouvernement ?<sup>1</sup>

Ni l'un ni l'autre. La citation du journal présentée dans l'[ouvrage](https://books.google.ca/books?id=QVQqEAAAQBAJ&pg) remonte à il y a plus de 100 ans et il s'agit d'un document d'archive. On sait très bien qu'il y a une différence entre traduire un propos d'une autre époque et utiliser le concept de « race » comme s'il était fondé scientifiquement en rédaction.

On emploiera le mot correspondant pour traduire un texte d'archive. En rédaction, on pourra mettre de côté de terme « race », non fondé scientifiquement, et employer l'adjectif associé (Asiatique etc.) comme nom.

Quant aux autres exemples, ils ne posent pas de difficulté particulière non plus, que ce soit le « lien entre santé et couleur de la peau/[groupe ethnique](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/17570777/groupe-ethnique) », « la couleur/la discrimination raciale comme vecteur/au centre de l'engagement » (il faut lire les [textes](https://www.proquest.com/openview/79eb51e6a51cd0127878c67372d6f6fa/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=18750&diss=y) pour comprendre plutôt que de rester prisonnier de leur titre) ou « être un symbole de ses origines ».

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> À mon avis, la proposition est fallacieuse à une multitude d'égards : elle propose un faux dilemme, elle s'appuie sur une prémisse fausse, à l'effet que la raison du déclin de l'intérêt du concept de *race* repose sur une « directive de l'État » alors qu'elle repose plutôt sur un consensus scientifique, elle confond traduction et révisionnisme, et finalement tente d'installer l'État comme responsable d'un appauvrissement linguistique en traduction. La question choisit au hasard un extrait dont les propos sont récupérés par les anxieux identitaires contemporains de la sphère populiste anti-science craignant les manoeuvres de l'État profond.</sub>

Comment: Le fil de ma pensée dérivant j'ai repensé à [ce billet](https://www.radiofrance.fr/franceculture/podcasts/le-pourquoi-du-comment-histoire/pourquoi-les-erreurs-de-traduction-peuvent-fausser-le-sens-de-l-histoire-6005099) de Gérard Noiriel sur la traduction du langage scientifique et les considérations politiques.